# Should we have "Remastered"/"HD" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Some games (for example in the LoZ series) have been remade, or remastered, for new consoles. However, should we have new tags for these games? Should it depend on the game itself? Most remastered games have new features and/or mechanics, but there are some that have just had a graphic overhaul.

Should we create new tags for these games, or just edit the existing ones? Some suggestions of this that come to mind might be [halo-combat-evolved](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-combat-evolved) and [halo-anniversary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-anniversary) or [okami](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami) and [okami-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okami-hd).

We currently have [one such suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/133232) (get it while it's hot!) that brought this thought to my attention.

Comment: I saw the same edit in the queue, and wanted to ask the same question. I think it is a good idea to have both of them. Having more tags isn't bad, and it can strongly help people choosing the right tags, and thus getting a better answer.

Comment: TL;DR for the dupe, along with other prior conversations on the subject: if there are substantial gameplay *differences*, make a new tag. New content that does not replace old content, such as a bonus dungeon is *usually* not enough to make a new tag worth bothering. Reworked game mechanics, of course, are. Upsampled resolution and frame rates are almost certainly not.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Effectively what I was getting at with the whole "bonus features" vs "upscale gameplay". Thanks for clearing it up :)